# spark - eager loading and caching RDD while executing on localhost master

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

First question, is there anyway I can eagerly load RDD before applying any reduce function? If not I'll have to do dummy reduce function as I am trying to cache RDDs during my rest application startup!

Second, I dont see any caching happening even after running reduce function. I am using spark and spark sql. I am reading hdfs directory(part-r-*) using sparkcontext.  I tried to call cahce() on resulted JavaSchemaRDD after call to registerAsTable. But if I try to call cache() after JavaRDD is loaded then caching seems to work. What is difference in calling cache() on JavaRDD as opposed to JavaSchemaRDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no way in Spark to 'pre-warm' the RDD. Even if you mark RDD as cached with `cache()` or `persist()` function it would be cached only on calculation, and according to lazy computation model the calculation itself would be performed only when an `action` would be executed. The simplest action you might want to use that would cache the whole RDD is `count()`
2. Your data is persisted only when the calculation itself is performed, as I described above. There is no difference whether you call `cache()` on JavaRDD or JavaSchemaRDD object, it would be cached only after the action is executed on top of this RDD after you have called the `cache()` or `persist()`. As I told above, the simplest action to populate the cache is `count()` as it will go through all the RDD and cache all the partitions (if you have enough memory). Something like `take()` would cache only some of the partitions, `reduce()` would cause additional computations which are not needed in your case.

If it didn't answer your question, provide code examples

Comment: Thanks! count() works for 1st soln. 2nd questions was actually if I have cache() operation on JavaSchemaRDD as opposed to JavaRDD it won't cache even after compute phase for some reason. Example in answer section.

Comment: Rather than count, you should use `df.foreachPartition { _ => }`. This is because counting requires two stages (map and then reduce) whereas foreachPartition completes in a single stage, eliding shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

//during startup

`JavaSchemaRDD schemaRDD0 = sqlContext.applySchema(ObjAJavaRdd, ObjA.class);
schemaRDD0.registerAsTable(“tablename”);
schemaRDD0.cache()`

//during each request; there are several query request per call and spark loads RDD from file every time instead of caching it first time

`JavaSchemaRDD schemaRDD1 = sqlContext.sql(queryString);
JavaPairRDD<String, double[]> pairRDD = schemaRDD1.mapToPair(row -> transform(row));
JavaPairRDD<String, double[]> pairReducedRDD = pairRDD.reduceByKey((a,b) -> reduceterms(a, b));`

If I do following during startup it caches as expected 
`ObjAJavaRdd.cache()
JavaSchemaRDD schemaRDD0 = sqlContext.applySchema(ObjAJavaRdd, ObjA.class);
schemaRDD0.registerAsTable(“tablename”);`

Comment: Did you try `cacheTable()` instead? `cache()` should also work, at least worked for me. What is the Spark version you use?

Comment: Spark 1.0.2 . I see cacheTable() is available in SQLContext but I am using JavaSQLContext. I can try javaSqlContxt().sqlContext().cacheTable(). Thanks

Comment: I think it is because of the version. `cache()` in 1.2.0 worked for me